# How to forward eclipse in a docker container through a linux proxy?

Tags: linux, ssh, docker, centos, x11

I have an Eclipse instance running on linux Ubuntu in a docker container. This container runs on a CentOS host with no physical display and I would like to forward X11 from the docker container to my laptop (running windows) through the CentOS host. 
Docker container runs with

```
docker run  --name docker-eclipse -p 5000:5000/tcp -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
```

While I can forward X11 from the host to my laptp with no problems, I'm not able to start eclipse inside the container, because it dies with "Cannot open display:".

What I'd like is

*laptop --> remote host --> docker container running eclipse*

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Are you able to run `xeyes` from within Docker? Did you try to run this command locally?

Comment: X11 forwarding works on the host, so xeyes works as well. It does not work inside the docker container.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "are you able to run `xeyes` from with Docker?" not only on the remote host. Is the user running eclipse root? Did you try to run it locally using Docker? (removing the ssh forwarding)

Comment: xeyes inside the docker container fails with "Error: Can't open display: localhost:12.0".

Comment: Was this test done locally (without the remote)? Is the user running eclipse root? It's a bit tough to help you with so few details.

Comment: This docker image run locally on a linux machine with a physical video device works fine and shows the eclipse window. When the image is brought up on a server without video device (for instance a VPS) it does not work. Arguably it is due to the lack of a video device, in fact, if I start on the remote host a Xvfb server simulating a virtual dispaly, eclipse starts normally. My question is about how to correctly setup the X11 forrwarding between client,remote host and docker container.

Comment: I think I understood the issue here. If you try to run this command with X being launched then, when you share `/tmp/.X11` it just doesn't work because `/tmp/.X11` is:
 - Not supposed to exist on the remote host
 - Not supposed to use the `/tmp/.X11` of the remote host but yours (the client).

Comment: What do you suggest to fix the problem?

Comment: To share through `sshfs` (**might** work) your `/tmp/.X11`

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more your suggestion, maybe in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This **might** work (`server` is assumed to be the remote host running Docker, `laptop` is assumed to be the local host from which you want the GUI):

1. Connect to the `server`.
2. Mount through `sshfs` the `laptop`'s .X11 socket from the server: `user@server:$sshfs laptop:/tmp/.X11-unix /tmp/.X11-unix`.
3. Start the container with something like `user@laptop:ssh -X server docker run  --name docker-eclipse -p 5000:5000/tcp -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix`.

I'm not sure this would work, and it does not *feel* the cleanest way of doing so, but what you want to perform is quite.... unusual (though it would be something really great !!).

Comment your feedback !

Comment: My laptop runs Windows, Does it work with X11 sockets as well?